# How do you get a list of the available sizes for a given UIfont in swift 3.0

Tags: ios, swift, fonts, uifont

IOS 10.x Swift 3.0

Got this code for listing out the fonts available, works well. But want the sizes too, much like you see in a panel like this...

```
var fontFamilies = UIFont.familyNames as [String]
var fontNames = [String]()
var fontSizes = [String]()

func listFonts() {
    for  i in 0 ..< fontFamilies.count {
        let fontFamily: NSString = fontFamilies[i] as NSString
        let localFontNames = UIFont.fontNames(forFamilyName: fontFamilies[i]) as [String]
        saveFont(fontNames: localFontNames)
    }
    NSLog ("%@:", fontNames)
}
```

But I want to know the available sizes, where does font book get this information from?

[image]

Comment: You can give any size to any of the font.

Comment: Yes. I know, but there must be some rational behind the jump between 14 points you see in this snapshot and 18 points. Yes I can ask for 15 or 16 too, but some reason it is suggesting 14 or 18 only?

Comment: No. You can see all the font in panel this is static list of font size in font book. Check any of the font family list will be the same.

Comment: I think you want to read this: http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/54676/reasonable-big-default-font-sizes

Comment: Thank you Devran, that is the answer to my question!